# Save email from first table to second table

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an application. I need the email of the existing user, which is already saved in the first table, and save it into the second table. Which queries or functions do I need to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You just need two fetch the user and then create an insert function to reinsert it into another table.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fetch the user's email by passing on the valid row id:

```
public Cursor getRecord(long id) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = this.database.query(true, databaseTable, new String[] {columnId, columnName, columnEmail}, columnId + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Please note, you may have different columns so change the `String[]` array with your designated columns. Now, we can create another function to save that email in another table like so:

```
public long insertExistingUser(String name, String email) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(columnName, name);
    contentValues.put(columnEmail, email);

    return this.database.insert(otherDatabaseTable, null, contentValues);
}
```

This will insert the other user's information into the other table. In order for this to work in your application:

```
DatabaseAdapter db = new DatabaseAdapter(this);

db.open();

Cursor cursor = db.getRecord(current_user_id);

if (db.insertExistingUser(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2)) > 0)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Old user's info was inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

db.close();
```

The `cursor.getString(1)` requires a number that indicates what column it is. Usually, `0` is the id column which you use to get the user's email.